# MVC 5 project problem with accessing the SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework-6

I have created a simple project with login and verification. However, I don't know why I cannot use gmail to register the program. During I put my gmail account for registration, I will met this error.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
```

During testing this project, I have use hotmail account yao0529@live.com and gmail account yuky0529@gmail.com to register. The hotmail account is register success but gmail cannot. Both of the information for register are exactly same except email.

The code below is normal data class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Food_Founder.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
    public partial class User
    {
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMetaData
    {

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 8 characters or numbers are required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password is not match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is another normal data class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Food_Founder.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
        public System.Guid ActivationCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The picture below is my database details.

[image]

Below the code is my controller class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Food_Founder.Models;

namespace Food_Founder.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //Registration
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Post Registration
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified,ActivationCode")]User user)
        {

            //Model Validation
            bool Status = false;
            string message = "";

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                #region Email is already exist
                var isExist = IsEmailExist(user.Email);
                if (isExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email already exist");
                    return View(user);
                }
                #endregion

                #region Generate Activation Code
                user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                #endregion

                #region Password Hashing
                user.Password = Crypto.Hash(user.Password);
                user.ConfirmPassword = Crypto.Hash(user.ConfirmPassword);
                #endregion

                user.IsEmailVerified = false;

                #region Save Data to Database
                using (myDatabaseEntities myDatabase = new myDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    myDatabase.Users.Add(user);
                    myDatabase.SaveChanges();

                    //Send Email to User
                    SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.Email, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
                    message = "Registration successfully done. Account activation link" +
                        "has been send to your Email:" + user.Email + "Please go check and activate your account";
                    Status = true;
                }
                #endregion

            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(user);
        }

        //Verify Email


        //Verify Email Link


        //Login


        //Login POST


        //Logout



        [NonAction]
        public Boolean IsEmailExist(string email)
        {
            using (myDatabaseEntities myDatabase = new myDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = myDatabase.Users.Where(a => a.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
                return v != null;
            }
        }

        [NonAction]
        public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string email, string activationCode)
        {
            var verifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;
            var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

            var fromEmail = new MailAddress("yukwokyao2@gmail.com", "yukwokyao");
            var toEmail = new MailAddress(email);
            var fromEmailPassword = "********";
            string subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

            string body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your FoodFounder account is" +
                "successfully created. Please click the below link to verify your FoodFounder account" +
                "<a href = '" + link + "' >" + link + "</a>";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
            };

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            })
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserID]          INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FirstName]       VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [LastName]        VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [Email]           VARCHAR (256)    NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth]     DATE             NULL,
    [Password]        NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [IsEmailVerified] BIT              NOT NULL,
    [ActivationCode]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] ON
```

Here I met the new problem is when I set the auto-increment for database primary key, it show this error

```
SQL70001 this statement is not recognized in this context
```

This error is showed as there is a red line under the `SET`. Plus, I can't find any database script for set the BuildAction as None
Anywhere, if anything I miss put please inform me ya.. Thank you.

Comment: care to check InnerException? it probably says what is missing or not right.

Comment: @Siavash But where to check it? I didnt write any exception code for that.

Comment: @Siavash Also, there is a details inside this error
```SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__User__1788CCACEC6305F0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.```

Comment: that's your issue then. Don't duplicate your primary key. SQL should generally be generating the primary key value automatically (via an auto_increment field) - the .NET code should not usually be specifying the key value. You haven't shown the code where you actually try to insert the data, but I would guess maybe you are specifying an ID where you shouldn't. Maybe you should show that code, since that's where the error is occurring...

Comment: P.S. Why did you tag this with MySQL? From your screenshot you appear to be using SQL Server. You will get better help if you read the tag descriptions and then select the correct ones, because then people with the relevant expertise will see your question, instead of people for whom it is not related. An entity-framework tag would probably be appropriate, too. You can use the "edit" button just below the blue tags to amend your question.

Comment: @ADyson Owhh ok. Thanks for remind me the tag.

Comment: @ADyson So I should make a function that UserID (my primary key) automatically plus one when another user register right?

Comment: you don't need to make a function, no. In fact that's the opposite of what you should do - it will be prone to creating duplicates when there is more than one person using your system at the same time. Let the database handle it automatically by setting your ID field to be an IDENTITY field with auto-increment. You can easily google how to set that up, it takes 2 second in SSMS to configure it (see http://techfunda.com/howto/16/set-auto-increment-column). It should be standard practice generally for most tables. A database design course / tutorial would introduce you to the concept as well.

Comment: @ADyson I have set the increment inside my database for primary key but now i facing another question in ```SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.```

Comment: After I met this problem, I go to set up my Identity_ insert by ```SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON``` in my sql database and met another problem that the ```SET``` statement is not recognized in this context.

Comment: "Cannot insert explicit value" ...in that case, please change your C# code so it does not try to insert a value for the ID. It should not attempt to provide any value for this field, even a default one. If, as I mentioned earlier, you post the relevant code where you actually create the object and try to insert it, we could help you with doing that if you are unsure. (Changing the identity_insert setting is not the solution here, as that just defeats the point of using autoincrement. identity_insert is intended for specific situations, but this isn't one of them.)

Comment: P.S. I kind of thing if you follow an introductory tutorial for entity framework / MVC (such as the ones provided by Microsoft) it should have shown you how to set up the database and the models correctly and this issue would not arise. Did you follow any such guide?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry about no enough sufficient code to you and I just update the question for other code.

Comment: @ADyson YA, I got find a youtube video for create this project. Here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSJFjuWFTdA

Comment: Yes and at 4:12 it tells you to add the Identity keyword to the table, which it seems you didn't do. IMHO it's always easier to follow a written tutorial so you can copy/paste the basic parts from it. Anyway right now you probably need to tell your EDMX to update from the database so that it understands that UserID is now an identity field.

Comment: P.P.S. Just so you know, you don't even need to create your own login system, unless it's for academic interest. ASP.NET Identity provides this kind of functionality out of the box. Generally that will give you an easier, better, safer, more secure experience without the risk of introducing security bugs in your own implementation which have already been dealt with by Microsoft's experts.

Comment: @ADyson What keyword I want to put to the table? I thought I have put ``` IDENTITY (1, 1)``` for the primary key already.

Comment: You can't have done it to begin with, otherwise you would have seen the error `Cannot insert explicit value`  from the start. Instead you had a different error originally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198941/discussion-between-john-lee-and-adyson).